Unable to translate the notice about updated Moderator Agreement
I know that the self Moderator Agreement is not translatable due to some legal issues. But I expect that the notice regarding the updated agreement should be translatable. Unfortunately I don't see related strings on traducir side.



Text version:

The new Moderator Agreement is ready for you to accept. You have until August 8, 2024, to review it and make your decision. For more information, see the Moderator Teams post.

At the same time notice on the moderator dashboard level is translatable (translated):



Related bug report: Moderator agreement acceptance notice should be made translatable
